# zsh completion for custom script

Tags: command-line, zsh, autocomplete

I have `zsh completion` for my custom script. It takes 3 optional arguments `--insert`, `--edit`, `--rm` and it completes files from given path:

```
#compdef pass

_pass() {

  local -a args

  args+=(
    '--insert[Create a new password entry]'
    '--edit[Edit a password entry]'
    '--rm[Delete a password entry]'
  )

  _arguments $args '1: :->directory'

  case $state in
  directory)
    _path_files -W $HOME/passwords -g '*(/)' -S /
    _path_files -W $HOME/passwords -g '*.gpg(:r)' -S ' '
    ;;
  esac
}
```

I need to add another option `-P`, that will also be offered for completion (when I type `-` and <kbd>TAB</kbd>), but does not offer path completion. This option should only take a string. So it should not match a path, and also it should not offer the other options if `-P` has been specified.

How can I add this new option to my completion script?

## UPDATE:

The completion does not work for option `-P`, ie when i do:

```
pass -P <TAB>
```

it completes nothing because option -P needs a string. This is good. But, when I do

```
pass -P foo <TAB>
```

it also does not complete nothing. But it should complete directories in current path. How can do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presuming all of the options you mentioned are mutually exclusive with each other, then the solution is as follows:

```bsh
#compdef pass

_pass() {
  local -a args=(
      # (-) makes an option mutually exclusive with all other options. 
      '(-)--insert[Create a new password entry]'
      '(-)--edit[Edit a password entry]'
      '(-)--rm[Delete a password entry]'
      '(-)-P:string:'
      '1:password entry:->directory'
  )

  _arguments $args

  case $state in
    directory)
      _path_files -W $HOME/passwords -g '*(/)' -S /
      _path_files -W $HOME/passwords -g '*.gpg(:r)' -S ' '
      ;;
  esac
}
```

Documentation here: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-_005farguments

Comment: works great. Thank you.

Comment: sorry, I have discovered small problem: Now it seems the completion requires an argument, before it completes from the path `$HOME/passwords`. Before your change, I could also use my script without any argument, ie `pass TAB` would complete from the path. Now it only works when i provide an argument.

Comment: That's easily fixed: Just add `':password entry:->directory'` to the `(options)` group. I've updated my answer with it.

Comment: when I do `pass -P foo <TAB>`, it does not complete anything. It should complete directories in current path. See my update for more details. Would you know how to fix that?

Comment: @400theCat I updated my answer to add the behavior you want for `-P`. Will you award me the bounty before it expires?